Error during set up of lwc local development server in VS Code
Whenever I'm trying to run 'sfdx plugins:install @salesforce/lwc-dev-server', I get a bunch of errors and I am unable to install the packages. Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue?



As the error message suggests
'node.js' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Please install node.js and try again

I have node.js instaled and I have verified the same as when I do 'node -v' in vs code, it shows me the current version of node.
